# PHP Call variable in function inside a class

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

I have a PHP class, whith 2 functions:

```
class insert 
{

public function firstNumber() {
$first = 1;
}

public function secondNumber() {
$second = 2;
}

public function sum() {
$end = $first + $second;
echo $end;
}
}
```

So, I want to call the first variable from the `firstNumber()` function, and the second variable from the `secondNumber()` function. How can I do this?

Comment: http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials

Comment: This reads as if you never even bothered to take only a short glimpse into the documentation. Or a tutorial. Or a "getting started" guide. _Why not?_ http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: This question seems at least _partially_ unrelated to the fact that the functions are in a class; it seems like sort of a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) question as well. Just to be clear - the `$first` and `$second` variables in the `sum()` method are _not_ the same variables that are in `firstNumber()` and `secondNumber()`. That's why assigning them to `$this->first` and `$this->second` is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [PHP OOP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).  Use object properties using `$this`:

```
class insert 
{
    public function firstNumber() {
        $this->first = 1;
    }

    public function secondNumber() {
        $this->second = 2;
    }

    public function sum() {
        $end = $this->first + $this->second; // or use $this->end if you need it later
        echo $end;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this` is-> a [Possible duplicate of PHP OOP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, but it wouldn't let me choose that as a dupe ;-)

Comment: I know... I linked to the URL you left in there *haha!* ;-)

Comment: It would be nice if that option were available though. Now why didn't they think of that? Oh yeah, they have... reason that PHP.net probably couldn't handle the extra traffic ;-)